# Exception serializing Enumeration field to BSON

Tags: mongodb, scala, serialization, playframework

I am using PlayFramework 2.6 with SCALA and mongodb-driver.

Struggling with Eumeration serialization on write.

When I try to insert object containing enum fields I get exception:

```
Caused by: org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class scala.Enumeration$Val.
at org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecCache.getOrThrow(CodecCache.java:46)
at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:63)
at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:37)
at org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.macrocodecs.MacroCodec.writeValue(MacroCodec.scala:167)
at org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.macrocodecs.MacroCodec.writeValue$(MacroCodec.scala:162)
```

I created codecs for object itself,
also tried to create codec for enumeration class type, but looks like it correct way.

```
  val routeTypeCodec: CodecProvider = Macros.createCodecProvider[RouteTypeClass]
  val routeCodec: CodecProvider = Macros.createCodecProviderIgnoreNone[Route]
```

enumeration:

```
class RouteTypeClass extends TypeReference[RouteType.type]

object RouteType extends Enumeration {
  type RouteType = Value
  val Repeat, OneTime = Value
}
```

object for save:

```
case class Route(
 ...
 routeType: RouteType
 ...
);
```

How to write codec for enum fields, except defining this fields as a String.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: After additional testing, this only works with a single Enumeration in your registry. If you created additional Enumerations, only the *first* one put in the registry will work.

I have been bashing my head against this issue for awhile, and found a solution. This is works in Scala 2.13, Play 2.8

I started by writing a custom codec, but I still got a `Can't find a codec for CodecCacheKey{clazz=class scala.Enumeration$Val` error. It seems the codec registry will recognize an codec for Enumeration covers `Enumeration$Value`, but still finds `Enumeration$Val`, even though its a private class and won't be used directly. There's a long open issue in the [public mongodb jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-3553).

I worked around it by making a class extending `CodecProvider` which has a generic Codec for `Enumeration#Value`, and checks the className the `scala.Enumeration$Val` and `scala.Enumeration$Value`

```
class EnumerationCodecProvider(enumeration: Enumeration) extends CodecProvider {
 
  def enumerationCodec[E <: Enumeration](enumeration: E): Codec[E#Value] = new Codec[E#Value] {
    override def decode(reader: BsonReader, decoderContext: DecoderContext): E#Value =
      enumeration.withName(reader.readString())
 
    override def encode(writer: BsonWriter, value: E#Value, encoderContext: EncoderContext): Unit =
      writer.writeString(value.toString)
 
    override def getEncoderClass: Class[E#Value] = classOf[E#Value]
  }
 
  def isEnumVal[T](clazz: Class[T]): Boolean = {
    clazz.getName.equals("scala.Enumeration$Val") ||
      clazz.getName.equals("scala.Enumeration$Value")
  }
 
  override def get[T](clazz: Class[T], registry: CodecRegistry): Codec[T] = {
    if (isEnumVal(clazz)) {
      enumerationCodec(enumeration).asInstanceOf[Codec[T]]
    } else {
      null
    }
  }
 
}
 
object Example extends Enumeration {
  type Example = Value
  val id: Example = Value("id")
 
  val codecProvider: CodecProvider = new EnumerationCodecProvider(Example)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop the use of enums. Instead, use sealed trait and case classes. Not too elegant solution, but works.

```
sealed trait RouteType {
  def routeType: String
}

case class Repeat() extends RouteType {
  override val routeType: String = "Repeat"
}
case class OneTime() extends RouteType {
  override val routeType: String = "OneTime"
}

objet RouteType {
  def parseFromString(value: String): Option[RouteType] = {
    Vector(Repeat(), OneTime().find(_.routeType == value)
  }
}
```

and write a custom BSON codec for these

```
import org.bson.{BsonReader, BsonWriter}
import org.bson.codecs.{Codec, DecoderContext, EncoderContext}

class RouteTypeCodec extends Codec[RouteType] {
  override def encode(
    writer: BsonWriter,
    value: RouteType,
    encoderContext: EncoderContext
  ): Unit = writer.writeString(value.routeType)
  override def getEncoderClass: Class[RouteType] = classOf[RouteType]
  override def decode(reader: BsonReader,
                        decoderContext: DecoderContext): RouteType= {
    val value = reader.readString()
    val result = RouteType.parseFromString(value)
    if (result.isDefined) result.get else throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such RouteType")
  }
}
```